# Convex optimisation: primal, dual problems, feasibility, etc.

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

I am new to convex optimisation and I am struggling to understand basic concepts such primal and dual problems, feasibility of the primal or dual problem, Slater condition, slackness etc.

Is there any easy to understand but not excessively long source online that you would recommend for me to go through to start understanding the intuition of these concepts? E.g. online course with examples would be great.

Comment: It would help to know something about your mathematical background.  Have you taken courses in calculus, linear algebra, and real analysis? ,Have you taken any proof-based mathematics courses?   Are you more interested in applying convex optimization techniques in your own field, or are you interested in learning the theory of convex optimization?

Comment: Hi Brian, I know calculus and linear algebra, never taken real analysis though. I am interested in learning the theory of convex optimization, so getting an understanding of the meaning of the concepts i have mentioned in the question (e.g. how to show that a primal problem is feasible and when, how to construct the dual problem, what are the KKT conditions, etc).

Comment: Honestly, my top recommendation would be to take some proof-based mathematics before diving into this subject.